# the keytool command to get facebook app signature on android doesn't return any id?

Tags: android, facebook

I have some problem to generate the hash id for facebook.
I've try a lot of command but no one generate an id when insert the password android but with any other password return a wrong id

I've try with:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore ~/.android/debug.keystore | openssl sha1 -binary | openssl base64`

I can't understand where is the problem becouse it seems to work with the wrong password, but the command doesn't return nothing whith the password 'android'

Answer (score 0):

Verify that you have the filepath is correct.  If it is, then it must be some clowny issue with your debug.keystore.  I would try deleting the debug.keystore as quoted from the [Android Documentation](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

> To fix this problem, simply delete the debug.keystore file. The default storage location for AVDs is in ~/.android/ on OS X and Linux, in C:\Documents and Settings\.android\ on Windows XP, and in C:\Users\.android\ on Windows Vista and Windows 7.
>
> The next time you build, the build tools will regenerate a new keystore and debug key.

I would try that.  Delete the debug.keystore file and let Eclipse regenerate it.  Try the command again and see if it works with the password "android".